# Powerpoint VBA to maximize the ribbon

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbon

Does someone know the Powerpoint VBA syntax for maximizing (show tabs and commands) and intermediate-sizing (Show tabs only) the powerpoint ribbon?

The following works for minimizing the ribbon, but I can't find anything to bring the ribbon back to its normal size.

Thank you

```
' minimize the ribbon    
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
    
' show tabs only on the ribbon?
xxx?
    
' maximize the ribbon (show tabs and commands)?
xxx?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
```

is a toggle, so to maximise you just run it again. When minimized, the tabs still display. To hide them completely:

```
Sub HideRibbon()
    CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, you're right! Thank you! Do you know of some documentation somewhere that explains that? Or that gives a list of things you can pass to ExecuteMso? I'm also wondering how to show/hide the Format Background sidebar panel, and others.

Comment: Sorry, there's not too much documentation from Microsoft. There are a handful of professional PowerPoint programmers and we keep each other up to date with our online posts. A useful resource are Microsoft's collection of "Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers". This is a set of Excel workbooks that list the command names, ID numbers and where they are found in the program interface. You can download them from here, the 2016 collection is the most recent: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Comment: I re-read your post. There's very little VBA control over task panes and the backstage. You basically can show or hide them. For programmatic control, you need to use VSTO or C#/VB and the Open XML SDK to get at them, a steep learning curve. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-ui-customization?view=vs-2019

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your replies. VSTO is no problem because that is what I use. I did see the Office Fluent identifiers in my search but wondered if Fluent had anything to do with my goal. I will investigate further.